# multiple method's Foreign key Constraint

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I have two seperate tables **Table A** and **Table B**, each table's data was inserted separately from different pages.

Now I wanted to insert all the data from one page adding a foreign key **(fk_BId**) in **Table A**.

The issue is how to give **fk_BId** the newly created Id from the data that I insert from my application, 
in order for the created **AId** to be equal to the created **BId** like this:

---

**TABLE A**

---

AId    = 1

fk_BId = **2**

Item 1  = A

Item 2 = B

---

**TABLE B**

---

BId = **2**

item 3 = D

item 4 = E

---

My Coding for adding the data individually looks something like this:

**WCF**

```
public void AddDataA(Obj obj)
{
    using (var result = new _Db())
    {
        var t = new A
        {
            item1 = obj.item1,
            item2 = obj.item2
        };
        result.A.Add(t);
        result.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public void AddDataB(Obj obj)
{
    using (var result = new _Db())
    {
        var t = new B
        {
            item1 = obj.item1,
            item2 = obj.item2
        };
        result.B.Add(t);
        result.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**WPF**

```
private void methodA()
{
    _Service service = new _Service();

        service.AddDataA(new Obj
        {
            item1 = txtitem1.Text,
            item2 = txtitem2.Text
        });

}

private void methodB()
{
    _Service service = new _Service();

        service.AddDataB(new Obj
        {
            item1 = txtitem1.Text,
            item2 = txtitem2.Text
        });     
}
```

I quess my question simply is how to do an Insert from a one page form into two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF supports your scenario. Firstly let's define a model with navigation properties:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Item1 { get; set; }
    public int? Item2 { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public partial class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Item1 { get; set; }

    public int? Item2 { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<A> A { get; set; } = new List<A>();
}
```

A Db context class will look as follows:

```
public partial class MyModel: DbContext
{
    public MyModel(): base("name=ConnectionStringName") {}

    public virtual DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<B> B { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<B>().HasMany(e => e.A).WithOptional(e => e.B).Map(e => e.MapKey("fk_Bld"));
    }
}
```

The code in *OnModelCreating* method is needed to tell EF that *fk_Bkld* is a foreign key. Now we can insert objects into DB:

```
using (var ctx = new MyModel())
{
    var a1 = new A { Item1 = 1, Item2 = 2 };
    var a2 = new A { Item1 = 2, Item2 = 3 };
    var b = new B { Item1 = 4, Item2 = 5, A = new List<A> { a1, a2 } };

    ctx.B.Add(b);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now you need to use a code like that in WCF method and call it from your application.